# How to fix [AWSTask exception] crash in AWSCore (AWS-sdk-ios)

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, swift3, aws-sdk

I use AWS-SDK for iOS 2.6.14 (latest through Cocoapods) and have faced next issue:

I got a message in Xcode console:

```
-[AWSTask exception]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17587ac00
```

And then application is crashed.

I've tried to prevent it by creating custom extension:

```
extension AWSTask {
    public func exception() {
        print("AWSTask exception method called")
    }
}
```

I know that it's awful solution but I have no idea how to fix the issue which source is in 3rd-party component.

Then I've got next message and app crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception of class 'AWSTask'
```

Exception breakpoint stops in AWSTask method `- (AWSTask *)continueWithExecutor:(AWSExecutor *)executor block:(AWSContinuationBlock)block cancellationToken:(nullable AWSCancellationToken *)cancellationToken`
On line `id result = block(self);`
(It's in source code of AWSCore framework).

I have searched for similar issues on AWS-sdk-ios GitHub and found some but it contain no answer.
I also created new [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/911) myself.

How can I fix it on my side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out I have `AWSMobileHubHelper.framework` integrated as static library. It seems it is the source of the crash.
I found `AWSMobilehubHelper`'s source at this repo.
But unfortunately can't manage to build a static library (because of building script issue).
Eventually, I've added the source to project with the bridging header.
And it seems to work now.